# Open an html bubble dialog in IE BHO (C++)

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, bho

Is there a way to open an html menu as a dialog for my IE BHO? I've tried looking over the web for a snippet that hints how to do that but with no clue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could create own dialog with browse control and put desired HTML here. Check [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3365/Embed-an-HTML-control-in-your-own-window-using-pla) how to do such dialog.